# How can I fix this “SQL Statement ignored” error?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following small function that does not compile:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insertarVentas(ID NUMBER, IDCliente NUMBER, nombre VARCHAR2, calle VARCHAR2, poblacion VARCHAR2, cp NUMBER, provincia VARCHAR2, dni VARCHAR2, 
telef1 VARCHAR2, telef2 VARCHAR2, telef3 VARCHAR2, fechaventa date, numerolinea NUMBER, IDProducto NUMBER, descripcion VARCHAR2, pvp NUMBER, stockactual NUMBER, cantidad NUMBER) AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO TABLA_VENTAS VALUES (ID, TIP_CLIENTE(IDCliente, nombre, TIP_DIRECCION(calle, poblacion, cp, provincia), dni, TIP_TELEFONOS(telef1, telef2, telef3)), fechaventa, 
TIP_LINEAS_VENTA(numerolinea, TIP_PRODUCTO(IDProducto, descripcion, pvp, stockactual), cantidad));
END insertarVentas;
```

The compiler gives me the following errors:

```
Error at line 4: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

2. telef1 VARCHAR2, telef2 VARCHAR2, telef3 VARCHAR2, fechaventa date, numerolinea NUMBER, IDProducto NUMBER, descripcion VARCHAR2, pvp NUMBER, stockactual NUMBER, cantidad NUMBER) AS
3. BEGIN
4. INSERT INTO TABLA_VENTAS VALUES (ID, TIP_CLIENTE(IDCliente, nombre, TIP_DIRECCION(calle, poblacion, cp, provincia), dni, TIP_TELEFONOS(telef1, telef2, telef3)), fechaventa, 
5. TIP_LINEAS_VENTA(numerolinea, TIP_PRODUCTO(IDProducto, descripcion, pvp, stockactual), cantidad));
6. END insertarVentas;
```

This is an insert into a object table, this is the code that table

```
CREATE TABLE TABLA_VENTAS OF TIP_VENTA(
IDVENTA PRIMARY KEY
)NESTED TABLE LINEAS STORE AS TABLA_LINEAS;

CREATE TYPE TIP_VENTA AS OBJECT(
IDVENTA NUMBER,

IDCLIENTE REF TIP_CLIENTE,
    CREATE TYPE TIP_CIENTE AS OBJECT(
    IDCLIENTE NUMBER,

    NOMBRE VARCHAR2(50),

    DIREC TIP_DIRECCION,
        CREATE TYPE TIP_DIRECCION AS OBJECT(
        CALLE VARCHAR2(50),
        POBLACION VARCHAR2(50),
        CODPOSTAL NUMBER(5),
        PROVINCIA VARCHAR2(40)
        );

    NIF VARCHAR2(9),

    TELEF TIP_TELEFONOS
        CREATE TYPE TIP_TELEFONOS AS VARRAY(3) OF VARCHAR2(15);
    );

FECHAVENTA DATE,

LINEAS TIP_LINEAS_VENTA,
    CREATE TYPE TIP_LINEAVENTA AS OBJECT(
    NUMEROLINEA NUMBER,

    IDPRODUCTO REF TIP_PRODUCTO,
        CREATE TYPE TIP_PRODUCTO AS OBJECT(
        IDPRODUCTO NUMBER,
        DESCRIPCION VARCHAR2(80),
        PVP NUMBER,
        STOCKACTUAL NUMBER
        );

    CANTIDAD NUMBER
    );

CREATE TYPE TIP_LINEAS_VENTA AS TABLE OF TIP_LINEAVENTA;
    );
```

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: (1) I think the parentheses are not balanced.  (2) You should include the column list when using `insert`.

Comment: @cjgmj Out of curiosity, why have you gone with this nested table approach? It's going to make querying the data more difficult than if you'd gone with a more traditional relational table design.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff the parentheses are balanced, the columns are in the third part

Comment: @cjgmj I'm no expert on nested tables, but what leaps out at me is that you've defined the table as an object of TIP_VENTA, so when you insert into it, you probably need to insert something that's also an object of TIP_VENTA. What Gordon meant by the column list is you would typically do an insert like: `insert into table (<list of table columns being inserted into>) values (<list of values corresponding to the listed table columns>);`

Comment: @Boneist I've done similar to the process and did not give me error

Comment: @Boneist It is just for a exercise class

Comment: @cjgmj tough class! *{;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're trying to insert into a table of an object something that isn't an object.

I've split out your object type populations into variables (rather than leaving them nested inside the insert statement as you did) which hopefully enables you to see what it is you're actually trying to insert:

```
create or replace procedure insertarventas (id number,
                                            idcliente number,
                                            nombre varchar2,
                                            calle varchar2,
                                            poblacion varchar2,
                                            cp number,
                                            provincia varchar2,
                                            dni varchar2,
                                            telef1 varchar2,
                                            telef2 varchar2,
                                            telef3 varchar2,
                                            fechaventa date,
                                            numerolinea number,
                                            idproducto number,
                                            descripcion varchar2,
                                            pvp number,
                                            stockactual number,
                                            cantidad number)
as
  v_tip_venta tip_venta;
  v_tip_cliente tip_cliente;
  v_tip_direccion tip_direccion;
  v_tip_telefonos tip_telefonos;
  v_tip_lineaventa tip_lineaventa;
  v_tip_lineas_venta tip_lineas_venta;
  v_tip_producto tip_producto;
begin
  v_tip_direccion := tip_direccion (calle,
                                    poblacion,
                                    cp,
                                    provincia);
  v_tip_telefonos := tip_telefonos (telef1,
                                    telef2,
                                    telef3);
  v_tip_cliente := tip_cliente (idcliente,
                                nombre,
                                v_tip_direccion,
                                dni,
                                v_tip_telefonos);
  v_tip_producto := tip_producto (idproducto,
                                  descripcion,
                                  pvp,
                                  stockactual);
  v_tip_lineaventa := tip_lineaventa (numerolinea,
                                      v_tip_producto,
                                      cantidad);
  v_tip_lineas_venta := tip_lineas_venta (v_tip_lineaventa);

  -- this is the step you were missing
  v_tip_venta := tip_venta (id,
                            v_tip_cliente,
                            fechaventa,
                            v_tip_lineas_venta);

  insert into tabla_ventas 
  values (v_tip_venta);
end insertarventas;
/
```

N.B. untested.

---

Ok, the presence of the REFs in the object type descriptions is what is causing the problems. However, I don't think it's necessary to use REF (not to mention that I couldn't work out how to make the code work with them! *{;-) ), so here is a working test case without the REFs:

```
drop procedure insertarventas;
drop table tabla_ventas;
drop type tip_venta;
drop type tip_lineas_venta;
drop type tip_lineaventa;
drop type tip_producto;
drop type tip_cliente;
drop type tip_telefonos;
drop type tip_direccion;

create type tip_direccion as object (calle varchar2(50),
                                     poblacion varchar2(50),
                                     codpostal number(5),
                                     provincia varchar2(40));

create type tip_telefonos as varray(3) of varchar2(15);

create type tip_cliente as object (idcliente number,
                                   nombre varchar2(50),
                                   direc tip_direccion,
                                   nif varchar2(9),
                                   telef tip_telefonos);

create type tip_producto as object (idproducto number,
                                    descripcion varchar2(80),
                                    pvp number,
                                    stockactual number);

create type tip_lineaventa as object (numerolinea number,
                                      idproducto tip_producto,
                                      cantidad number);

create type tip_lineas_venta as table of tip_lineaventa;

create type tip_venta as object (idventa number,
                                 idcliente tip_cliente,
                                 fechaventa date,
                                 lineas tip_lineas_venta);

create table tabla_ventas of tip_venta (idventa primary key)
  nested table lineas store as tabla_lineas;



create or replace procedure insertarventas (id number,
                                            idcliente number,
                                            nombre varchar2,
                                            calle varchar2,
                                            poblacion varchar2,
                                            cp number,
                                            provincia varchar2,
                                            dni varchar2,
                                            telef1 varchar2,
                                            telef2 varchar2,
                                            telef3 varchar2,
                                            fechaventa date,
                                            numerolinea number,
                                            idproducto number,
                                            descripcion varchar2,
                                            pvp number,
                                            stockactual number,
                                            cantidad number)
as
  v_tip_venta tip_venta;
  v_tip_cliente tip_cliente;
  v_tip_direccion tip_direccion;
  v_tip_telefonos tip_telefonos;
  v_tip_lineaventa tip_lineaventa;
  v_tip_lineas_venta tip_lineas_venta;
  v_tip_producto tip_producto;
begin
  v_tip_direccion := tip_direccion (calle,
                                    poblacion,
                                    cp,
                                    provincia);
  v_tip_telefonos := tip_telefonos (telef1,
                                    telef2,
                                    telef3);
  v_tip_cliente := tip_cliente (idcliente,
                                nombre,
                                v_tip_direccion,
                                dni,
                                v_tip_telefonos);

  v_tip_producto := tip_producto (idproducto,
                                  descripcion,
                                  pvp,
                                  stockactual);

  v_tip_lineaventa := tip_lineaventa (numerolinea,
                                      v_tip_producto,
                                      cantidad);

  v_tip_lineas_venta := tip_lineas_venta (v_tip_lineaventa);

  -- this is the step you were missing
  v_tip_venta := tip_venta (id,
                            v_tip_cliente,
                            fechaventa,
                            v_tip_lineas_venta);

  insert into tabla_ventas 
  values (v_tip_venta);
end insertarventas;
/
```

Comment: It give me this error: 

Error at line 43: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TIP_LINEAS_VENTA'

Comment: @cjgmj Hmm, in your create table code, you have a create type for TIP_LINEAVENTA, but not one for TIP_LINEAS_VENTA; which one is the correct object type name? (I referenced the one that you used in your original procedure)

Comment: I just see

 CREATE TYPE TIP_LINEAS_VENTA AS TABLE OF TIP_LINEAVENTA;

, then i think that it the same no?

Comment: Ah, I missed that. In which case, you need to define the record before inserting it into the v_tip_lineas_venta. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: It give me this error again: 

Error at line 44: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TIP_LINEAVENTA'

Comment: I'll have to have another look at this when I'm back in the office tomorrow.

Comment: TIP_LINEAS_VENTA is a collection, I think that It can help you

Comment: @cjgmj I've updated my answer to include a working test case, but I had to remove all the REFs from the type definitions in order to get it to work. You're on your own if you need to keep the REFs, as I couldn't work out how to make it work for record object types like you've got!

Comment: Thanks you, It works.

Answer (score 2):

The `PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored` message is usually just the top of the error stack and a following line will indicate what the actual issue is.

Having untangled your object creation statements and got them in an order that lets them all compile (and fixed at least one typo, and guess that a dangling comma was also a typo), creating your procedure gets:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- ------------------------------------
4/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
4/13     PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
```

You've defined TIP_VENTA with five fields:

```
CREATE TYPE TIP_VENTA AS OBJECT(
  IDVENTA NUMBER,
  IDCLIENTE REF TIP_CLIENTE,
  FECHAVENTA DATE,
  LINEAS TIP_LINEAS_VENTA,
  CANTIDAD NUMBER
);
```

But the object you create during your insert only has four values (reformatted to make it a bit more readable):

```
INSERT INTO TABLA_VENTAS VALUES (
  ID,
  TIP_CLIENTE(
    IDCliente,
    nombre, 
    TIP_DIRECCION(calle, poblacion, cp, provincia),
    dni,
    TIP_TELEFONOS(telef1, telef2, telef3)
  ),
  fechaventa, 
  TIP_LINEAS_VENTA(
    numerolinea,
    TIP_PRODUCTO(IDProducto, descripcion, pvp, stockactual),
    cantidad
  )
);
```

You've got `cantidad` inside the `TIP_LINEAS_VENTA()` constructor call, instead of after it:

```
INSERT INTO TABLA_VENTAS VALUES (
  ID,
  TIP_CLIENTE(
    IDCliente,
    nombre, 
    TIP_DIRECCION(calle, poblacion, cp, provincia),
    dni,
    TIP_TELEFONOS(telef1, telef2, telef3)
  ),
  fechaventa, 
  TIP_LINEAS_VENTA(
    numerolinea,
    TIP_PRODUCTO(IDProducto, descripcion, pvp, stockactual)
  ),
  cantidad
);
```

But that now gets:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- ------------------------------------------------------------------
9/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
20/5     PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected UDT got NUMBER
```

The fourth field of the TIP_VENTA is type TIP_LINEAS_VENTA, so you need to have a TIP_LINEAVENTA *within* that table constructor:

```
  TIP_LINEAS_VENTA(
    TIP_LINEAVENTA(
      numerolinea,
      TIP_PRODUCTO(IDProducto, descripcion, pvp, stockactual)
    )
```

Which then gets:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
9/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
22/7     PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected X.TIP_PRODUCTO got REF X.TIP_PRODUCTO
```

... because you're using actual objects instead of REFs to them, as the other type definitions expect. You'll need to decide whether to make them actual objects or fix the REFs...